# FQL: Querying comments by a certain friend

Tags: facebook-fql, comments

I want to query comments made by certain friend on my posts. Since "fromid" of "comment" table is not indexed I can't write a query like:

select text,fromid from comment where fromid = myfriendID

I am thinking of doing:

Select text,fromid 
from comment 
where post_id 
in (select post_id 
from stream 
where source_id = me())

Then compare each fromid with "myfriendID" to filter comments made by my friend from the rest. But this would take a long time to process.

Is there any alternative that is more efficient?